# pasting into stack exchange editor

Tags: support

I want to add the contents of an rc file to my question.when I paste it it looks fine in the editor but appears in my post with the formatting all wrong. on my end Ive used gedit  and gvim and the results are the same. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Standard reference: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks , I'm learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean it appears out of alignment and such?

You need to wrap long blocks of code-based files like rc files in code blocks.  Paste your code as normal, then select the entire block of code, and click the button on the formatting bar that looks like `{}` - this will format your block of text in code formatting and make it look like `vim` or `gedit` or `nano` would render it.

Comment: thanks Thomas, your answer was very helpful.